# C# generic type containing a list of itself when the type parameter is a base class

Tags: c#, generics

I've been trying to do something which I hoped would be simple, but turned otherwise.
I have a base class:

```
public class EntityBase
{
}
```

and two classes that inherit from it:

```
public class EntityA : EntityBase
{
}
public class EntityB : EntityBase
{
}
```

I want to use a container type that will wrap

1. An instance of `EntityBase`
2. A number of children which are other instances of the container type.

I want this container expose the exact type of the `EntityBase` instance it contains, so I use C# generics. But I could not manage to convince C# compiler to define a list of the container type (which has a type parameter now):

```
public class EntityNode<T> where T : EntityBase
{
    private T _node;

    private List<EntityNode<EntityBase>> _children = new List<EntityNode<EntityBase>>();                

    public EntityNode(T pNode)
    {
        _node = pNode;
    }

    public void AddChild(EntityNode<T> pNode) 
    {
        //_children.Add(pNode); //this is not going to work...
    }

    public T Root
    {
        get { return _node; }
        set { _node = value; }
    }        

}
```

Is it possible to allow `EntityNode` to contain a list which in turn contains `EntityNode<EntityA>`, `EntityNode<EntityB>` and `EntityNode<EntityBase>` instances?

Comment: I think you are going to use a [`Composite pattern`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) ;).

Comment: What you need is a `List` that contains entities of different types in the same moment?

Answer (score 0):

What about using `List<EntityNode<T>>` instead of `List<EntityNode<EntityBase>>`:

```
private List<EntityNode<T>> _children = new List<EntityNode<T>>();
```